# porque mi variable se imprime de esta forma?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

tengo un problema, nose porque mi variable se imprime de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Blade:**

```
<div>
<div class=" text-center">
    <p>
    <h5>Total: <b style="color: #fd2121;">${{$total}}</b></h5>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public $total;

public function showModal($id)
{

 
   $this->total =   Pedidos::where('habitacion_id', $id)->get('total');


}
```

ayuda por favor

intente de esta forma:${{$total->total}}
pero da error

Comment: Buen día, en `showModal` intenta ver lo que tiene `$this->total` utilizando `dd` (Dump and die), de esta forma `dd($this->total);`, así te vas a dar cuenta.  Cuando haces `get` te devuelve una colección de `Eloquent`. Si deseas únicamente obtener el valor de la columna "total" puedes utilizar `pluck('total')` antes de `get`, pero de todas formas, si tienes varias filas donde "habitacion_id" sea igual a "id" entonces te devolvería una colección, yo creo que tendrías que agregar algo más para obtener un único valor, por ejemplo `first()` pero no sé si el primer valor es el que te interesa.